# How to distribute multimodule project as single runnable jar file?

Tags: java, ant, build

I have a project that has many subprojects. And they all reference each other.

Now I need to run ant file to create runnable jar that contains all subprojects.

How to do this . I have already ant file but it lists only options contrib to download all dependencies and build to build all jars which are stored in lib folder?

So how to group all thse jars from lib folder into runnable single jar? And I also need dependencies from contrib folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try [jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) which allows you to combine multiple jars into (a single self-contained) one.

If you do not need the feature of renaming classes (to avoid name clashes etc.) you can simply use the jar task, see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html section "Merging archives"; the example there also contains a manifest entry to define a main class.

I think you can use jarjar much like the jar task, i.e. you should be able to add a manifest with it too.

Comment: Will that jar be runnable? How to make it runnable? How to use jarjar?